# Слетают стили пагинация GET WordPress

Tags: wordpress, get

Появилась непонятная ошибка. По адресу `https://site.ru/catalog/page/2/?keyword=12` сайт отображается иначе (причем неважно, какие GET данные передаются), будто бы часть стилей отлетела. Если же убрать GET данные и зайти сюда `https://site.ru/catalog/page/2/`, то все супер. На сайте есть кэширование, отключил и почистил файлы, однако ничего не поменялось. С чем может быть связано?

Comment: Всё-таки похоже на кеш, который отключается при наличии get-параметра в url.Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: может кеширование на уровне CDN ? например, в cloudflare